# UITableView contentInset different in iOS7 and iOS8

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, autolayout

I have a `UITableView` with autolayout (Bottom space to Bottom layout guide = 1)

There is a difference when I scroll down to the bottom,

In iOS8 is is hidden under the tab bar.

I tried to fix it with:
`self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame), 0.0f);`

It is getting fixed in iOS8 - screenshot:
[image]

But it has a white margin in iOS7 - screenshot:
[image]

Why is that? how can I fix it?

Comment: Why don't u disable the autolayout?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pin your UITableView to its superview instead of bottom layout guide. I had a similar problem and it worked for me. You can find this option in Editor > Pin > ... when viewing a xib file.

Comment: This isn't a sustainable solution because the tab bar height varies in different orientations